# Analytically continuing an inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analytic-continuation

A physicist here so apologies in advance for lack of rigor, QFT, Path integrals etc ;)

Consider the function $f(w)$. I know independently (due to causality and other physical properties) that $f(w)$ should be analytic everywhere in the complex w plane, except for a branch cut that extends from $w=w_{min}$ to $w = \infty$ on the real axis. But $f(w)$ can, in principle, have a singularity at infinity.

For a particular physical set up, I can compute $f(w)$ as

$$f(w) =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty  a_n w^n \tag{1}$$

which converges for all $w<1$. I want to understand the properties of (1) as $w \rightarrow \infty$ in the complex $w$ plane. My goal is to make sure that $\frac{f(w)}{w}$ does not have a singularity at complex infinity in this particular set up.

Now $a_n$ is a complicated expression and it is almost impossible to do the above sum. But what if I do this — I know that $a_n$ monotonically decreases with $n$. So $a_1$ is the maximum of all $a_n$. I can then write,

$$f(w) < a_1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty w^n \tag{2}$$

Summing the geometric series and dividing by $w$ I get

$$ \frac{f(w)}{w} < \frac{a_1 }{1-w} \tag{3} $$

I can analytically continue beyond the pole at $w=1$ in the complex plane, and obtain that $f(w)/w$ vanishes at infinity and I am done.

The question is — Is the above correct?

The reason I am worried is because in the last step I analytically continued beyond $w=1$. And equation (2) does not make sense for $w>1$ sine the RHS is divergent.

I can imagine that this cannot be true for a generic function, since it would be quite magical if an inequality in a certain domain can be analytically continued over a bigger domain. However I was hoping that the analytic properties of $f(w)$ mentioned above could help in some way.

Thank you!

Comment: No. Try with $\exp(w)-1$ ?

Comment: @reuns I don't understand. Are you suggesting to use exp(w) -1 to bound $\sum_n w^n$? I don't know how that helps.